# How to open the .wadl file for the doc.atlassian.com?

Tags: jira-rest-api, wadl

I download a .wadl file from https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.8.1/jira-rest-plugin.wadl

Do you know how to use it? Does it need to be imported by specific application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import your .wadl file with Postman.

1. Click Import
2. Select your file or folder, input your link, or paste your raw text. Postman will automatically recognize Postman data.
3. Confirm the name, format, and what you would like your data to import as, then click Import to bring your data into Postman.

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMrNE.png

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYMmE.png